# ¿Se puede omitir "que" en "Déjame que te lo cuente"?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

En la siguiente frase:

> Déjame **que** te lo cuente.

¿Podría quitar el "que"? ¿Por qué?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No se puede quitar, "que" es el pronombre relativo que une la oración principal "déjame" con la subordinada "te lo cuente".

---

You can't remove "que", it's a relative pronoun that links the main clause "déjame" with the subordinate "te lo cuente".